# How to access redmine log folder inside a docker after a docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, redmine

I am a noob with docker, and I try to implement a redmine+mysql container  in Windows environment and add production mysql dump in it after that.

I have an issue when trying to access to redmine after my execution of sql script production dump, after sql launch I only have Internal error when browsing redmine with docker. 
I don't know how to change the database name in the data-compose file , if I replace 'redmine' with anything else  my script is broken.

Also I don't know how I can access to redmine error logs folder in my docker to fix the issue.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.5.47
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - .\mysql_files\data-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - .\mysql_files\backup-mysql:/var/lib/mysql/backup
      - .\mysql_files\dump-mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: monmdp
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine

  redmine:
    image: redmine:4.0.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .\redmine_files\files:/usr/local/redmine/files
      - .\redmine_files\logs:/var/log/redmine
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: monmdp
```

as you can see I tried to access to redmine log folder  in this line :

```
    - .\redmine_files\logs:/var/log/redmine
```

but the folder is still empty  :(

expected result : can browse redmine with production data dump

current result : Can't browse redmine and can't access log folder to check what's wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I ran the same on MacOS (removing the volumes from service db) and it works. I can open the webpage http://localhost:8080 and browse. In docker you normally see the logs through docker commands. Either run "docker-compose up" without the -d flag, this way  you see the logs as it starts. Or use "docker-compose logs -f" to see the logs while containers are running

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to access the logs of redmine container but you found the `.\redmine_files\logs` directory empty. First, you need to check whether there are logs in the docker `/var/log/redmine` directory or not. You can do so by running commands in redmine shell itself. Use the command `docker exec -it redmine /bin/bash` to move to redmine shell and `cd` to `/var/log/redmine` to check if the logs are present there or not. If you don't find the logs there then that means that there was not logs to be replicated to `./redmine_files/logs`. 
If you find the logs in `/var/log/redmine` then there must be some issue with your docker-compose file, but it seems fine to me. Also, as @Mihai has suggested you can check the logs of redmine using the command `sudo docker-compose logs redmine` to see if it is running properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

this docked image host redmine under /usr/src/redmine/ so you should use

`- .\redmine_files\logs:/usr/src/redmine/log`